# using streams vs actors for periodic tasks

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, actor, akka-stream

Im working with akka/scala/play stack.

Usually, im using stream to perform certain tasks. for example, I have a stream that wakes every minute, picks up something from the DB, and call another service to enrich its data using an API and save the enrichment to the DB.

something like this:

```
class FetcherAndSaveStream @Inject()(fetcherAndSaveGraph: FetcherAndSaveGraph, dbElementsSource: DbElementsSource)
                                     (implicit val mat: Materializer,
                                      implicit val exec: ExecutionContext) extends LazyLogging {

  def graph[M1, M2](source: Source[BDElement, M1],
                    sink: Sink[BDElement, M2],
                    switch: SharedKillSwitch): RunnableGraph[(M1, M2)] = {

    val fetchAndSaveDataFromExternalService: Flow[BDElement, BDElement, NotUsed] =
      fetcherAndSaveGraph.fetchEndSaveEnrichment

    source.viaMat(switch.flow)(Keep.left)
      .via(fetchAndSaveDataFromExternalService)
      .toMat(sink)(Keep.both).withAttributes(supervisionStrategy(resumingDecider))

  }


  def runGraph(switchSharedKill: SharedKillSwitch): (NotUsed, Future[Done]) = {
    logger.info("FetcherAndSaveStream is now running")
    graph(dbElementsSource.dbElements(), Sink.ignore, switchSharedKill).run()
  }
}
```

I wonder, is this better than just using an actor that ticks every minute and do something like that? what is the comparison between using actors for this and stream?

trying to figure out still when should I choose which method (streams/actors). thanks!!

Comment: I prefer using the akka streams approach if you don't need to store any state inside the actor. Actors are for state, not for concurrency, see https://www.chrisstucchio.com/blog/2013/actors_vs_futures.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use both, depending on the requirements you have for your solution which are not listed there. The general concern you need to take into consideration - actors more low-level stuff than streams, so they require more code and debug.

Basically, streams are good for tasks where you have a relatively big amount of data you need to process with low memory consumption. With streams, you won't need to start to stream each `n` seconds, you can set this stream to run along with the application. That could make your code more concise by omitting scheduler logic.
I will omit your DI and architecture stuff, write solution with pseudocode:

```scala
val yourConsumer: Sink[YourDBRecord] = ???
val recordsSource: Source[YourDBRecord] = 
val runnableGraph = (Source repeat ())
  .throttle(1, n seconds)
  .mapAsync(yourParallelism){_ =>
    fetchReasonableAmountOfRecordsFromDB
  } mapConcat identity to yourConsumer
```

This stream will do your stuff. You even can enhance it with more sophisticated logic to adapt the polling rate according to workloads using feedback loop in graph api. Also, you can add the error-handling strategy you need to resume in place your stream has crashed.

Moreover, there's alpakka connectors for DBS capable of doing so, you can see if solutions there fit your purpose, or check for implementation details.

What you can get by doing so - backpressure, ability to work with streams, clean and concise code with no timed automata managed directly by you. 
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-rate.html

You can also create an actor, but then you should do all the things akka streams do for you by hand, i.e. back-pressure in case you want to interop with streams, scheduler, chunking and memory management(to not to load 100000 or so entries in one batch to memory), etc.

Comment: i actually run the graph when the application starts. and than my stream source have tickInterval that i can set to whatever i want and im setting it up to 1 minut

Comment: It seems that your app has a tick interval to run stream since there's no polling logic inside stream itself. The proposed solution puts that logic inside stream reducing overall code amount.

Comment: `Source.tick(0 seconds, n seconds, ())` is clearer and more efficient that `(Source repeat ()).throttle(1, n seconds)`. Plus, the materializer of `tick` gives you a nice way to cancel the whole thing.